# Access individual characters in a string for ksh

Tags: ksh

I have a string as follows. I want to access individual characters in it and compare the characters. How to do so using ksh? The below is just pseudo code

```
str="hello"

if [[ str[i] == str[j] ]] ; then
    print yes
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${str:0:1}` is the zeroth character, `${str:1:1}` is the first, etc.  These are strings of length 1 starting at the given offset (the digits after the first colon specify the offset, the digits after the second colon specify the length).  To compare them, use test:

```
if test "${str:0:1}" = "${str:1:1}"; then ...
```

Note that in ksh, you cannot use a variable for the offset or length as you suggest in your comment, but that syntax will work in bash.  In ksh, you will probably need to resort to `eval`.

```
if eval test \${str:$i:0} = \${str:$j:0}; then ...
```

Note that this demonstrates one of the problems with eval.  I've dropped the quotes here because getting them correct with eval is painful, but without quotes this test will fail if the character in question is whitespace.

Comment: and how do u compare the two